# How can I send a userInfo dict using CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter()

Tags: ios, core-foundation, cfnotification

I need to send an object using `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter()` however, I'm noticing that whenever I send a notification using

```
const void *tkeys[1] = { @"testKey" };
const void *tvalues[1] = { @"testValue" };
CFDictionaryRef userInfo = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, tkeys, tvalues, 1, NULL, NULL);
CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                       CFSTR("foo"),
                                       object,
                                       userInfo,
                                       true);
```

then I find that in the observer callback, the userInfo dict is NULL. Is there something I am missing here? Is there some other way by which I can possibly send the userInfo object? I was looking at http://nshipster.com/inter-process-communication/ and the Distributed Notifications part, however whenever I use :

```
CFNotificationCenterRef distributedCenter =
CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter();
```

then I get an error `Invalid Use of Function` error whenever I try it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you read [the documentation for `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542572-cfnotificationcentergetdarwinnot?language=objc), you'll find this caveat:

> Several function parameters are ignored by Darwin notification
>   centers. To ensure future compatibility, you should pass NULL or 0 for
>   all ignored arguments.

`userInfo` is one of those parameters. `CFNotificationCenter.h` goes into more detail:

```
// For this center, there are limitations in the API. There are no notification "objects",
// "userInfo" cannot be passed in the notification, ...
// - CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(): the 'object', 'userInfo', and 'deliverImmediately' arguments are ignored.
```

Why? Dig a little deeper. The documentation also mentions that this type of notification center is built on the Core OS notify mechanism declared in [`notify.h`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Reference/usr_APIs/notify/index.html). If you look that up, you'll find that there is only one way to post a notification, by calling [`notify_post()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/darwinnotify/1433472-notify_post), which takes only a single string argument. There is no way to add additional data to the notification. This is a very old and rudimentary IPC mechanism that doesn't know anything about CoreFoundation data structures.

As for `CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter`, that isn't available on iOS.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That's a fantastic answer.

Comment: Jesus Apple developers are pretty lazy... I couldn't believe it when I saw it. The only way to do IPC on iOS and yep, there's nothing really there!